# E: failed to format /cache: permission denied

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, hardware, file-permissions

I am using a Blackview A60 Pro and I am stuck inside of the turn on screen. A couple of days ago I dropped it in a bucket of water and I have had it in rice since. I turned it on and it won't boot, I tried to recovery boot it, it wouldn't allow it. I tried to fastboot it,the command never finished. I cannot factory reset the phone as the permissions are denied. The phone seems to be working fine mechanically but I am unsure of what to do. Any Advice?